# HTML Tags showing up in browser when using CKEditor with ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, express, ckeditor

Here's my app.js file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.10.0/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
    <title>Jo Blog</title>
</head>
<body>

    {{{body}}}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">   
       // CKEDITOR.config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;

        CKEDITOR.replace('content', {
            plugins: 'wysiwygarea , toolbar, basicstyles, link',
            enterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR,
            autoparagraph: false,
            uiColor: '#AADC6E',
            removePlugins: 'elementspath'
        });

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

and here is the form I'm wanting it to affect - new.handlebars

```
<h1>New Blog</h1>

<form method="post" action="/blog">
    <label>Title</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="title"/><br>
    <label>Blog Content</label><br>
    <textarea name="content" id="ckEdit"></textarea><br>

    <input type="submit" name="submit">

</form>
```

Now the editor comes up just fine and I can write in it but when I hit submit the HTML tags are still all there eg "< p >Hello World< p >"

I've googled the crap out of this problem, and read everything I can find on here about it and tried everything I have read but nothing is working :/ Any ideas??

Comment: CKEditor mantains the HTML when you get the value for formatting the text just like you did in the editor, so, what's the problem ? You want to strip all the HTML and get just the text ?

Comment: @MatheusGomes I want the HTML tags too be there but not actually show up in the browser. At the moment when I write something the front end is literally showing the tags. I want the tags to be there but he invisible to the front end so "<p>hello world</p>" should just be seen as "hello world"

Comment: Maybe what you want is source code editing https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/examples/sourcearea.html

Comment: With the provided code and what you said, the only thing i can deduce is that you're writing HTML in text mode, so you're not being able do render it since CKEditor uses character references for escaping HTML special chars, like "<" and ">" (that would become "&lt;" and "&gt;" respectively)

Comment: @MatheusGomes I'm not writing in the HTML tags. They are automatically generated by ckeditor. I'm using ckeditor in the first place so I can generate a WYSIWYG look in input by the user. They don't show up when they are writing, but when it's saved to the database and then rendered in the browser the tags are being visibly shown while losing the actual formatting

Comment: Okay, can you reproduce the error in a working sample (use repl.it or something like it) and improve your question ? With the provided code is not possible to help you much further.

Answer (score 1):

I got your code to submit the form content and title without displaying the html tags in the browser.

The file ckeditor.js is loaded twice from two sources, once in the head by a cdn and again in the body.  **It's possible they are conflicting.**  I commented out the scripts in the body, and kept the cdn.ckeditor[...]ckeditor.js script in the head.

For testing purposes I removed the handlebars {{{body}}} and inserted the form directly into the html file.

I doubt the problem is in the form's action "/blog", but in order to see the returned result I changed the form's action to "form.php" (included below). The file form.php just sends the submitted content back to the browser. It does show the submitted content and title correctly displayed in the browser.

Here's "form.php" and the modified html files.

Hope this helps a little with trouble shooting.

**form.php**

```
<?php

$title = $_POST['title'];
$content = $_POST['content'];

print <<< PRINT
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>$title</title>
</head>

<body>
$content
</body>

</html>
PRINT;

?>
```

**HTML file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <!--<link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">-->
  <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.10.0/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
  <title>Jo Blog</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- changed the form's action from /blog to form.php for demo purposes -->
  <form method="post" action="form.php">
    <label>Title</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="title"/><br>
    <label>Blog Content</label><br>
    <textarea name="content" id="ckEdit"></textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
  </form>

  <!--
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js"></script>
  -->

  <script type="text/javascript">   
  // CKEDITOR.config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;

  CKEDITOR.replace('content', {
   plugins: 'wysiwygarea , toolbar, basicstyles, link',
   enterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR,
   autoparagraph: false,
   uiColor: '#AADC6E',
   removePlugins: 'elementspath'
  });

  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh wow thanks!! I've never used PHP before, what made you think to do that?

Comment: Great. Hope this helped. I used php just because it seemed the easiest way to test it. Take care!